# 'this' and click handler doesn't seem to go well together for me

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, click, this

I am having some trouble with my jQuery code. I am building a solution with pagination, I have one 'paginate' function (line 87) that I want to use on whatever array is needed to be manipulated.

**This is the paginate function that has two parameters. It's the "selected" argument that seems to mess things up because when I call it in the next code sample (the button click function) the $(this) keyword is referring to the button. Not the selected anchor as intended.**

```
function paginate(list, selected) {
// Removes all the items from the document. But because we are storing
// the items in an array, nothing is really lost.
removeStudents();

// Declaring the array that is to be filled with the students needed
// based on which pagination anchor element is clicked.
var arrToShow = [];

// Variable that decides where the counting of the students should start
// based on which pagination anchor element has the class of 'active'.
var headIndex = selected * maxStudents;

// Variable that goes together with the headIndex.
var tailIndex = headIndex - 10;

// Pushes the students, that have been chosen by the parameters of the function,
// to the arrToShow array.
for ( var i = tailIndex; i < headIndex; i++ ) {
    arrToShow.push(list[i]);
}
// Displays all of the objects within the arrToShow array.
for ( i = 0; i < arrToShow.length; i++ ) {
    $(".student-list").append(arrToShow[i]);
}
```

I have two parameters in the function: the list itself and which pagination anchor element that is currently active, or clicked. The issue seems to be that the $(this) refers to the button (line 57)  when I implement the pagination function inside of another function (I am referring to the button click function on line 57).

**This is the button function. It only works right now because I put a '1' for the second argument. I'd like for it to be like a global variable there that specifies which anchor argument that's selected.**

```
function buttonClicked() {
    removeStudents();
    // Store what's typed in to the search input in a variable.
    var userSearch = $("input").val();

    // Creating an array for the successfully searched array objects.
    var userSearchArr = [];

    // Iterating through every single student, looking for a match, if a match
    // is found, push it to the userSearchArr, then appending the objects
    // within that array to the student list container.
    $.each(allStudentsArr, function() {
        var studentName = $(this).find("h3").text();
        var filterThrough = studentName.indexOf(userSearch);
        console.log(filterThrough);

        if (filterThrough !== -1) {
            userSearchArr.push($(this));
        }

    });

    constructPagPages(userSearchArr.length);
    paginate(userSearchArr, 1);
    }
```

Is there some way of making the $(this) keyword within the click handler global, so that it refers to the click handlers $(this) and not to the $(this) that belongs to the function in which I'm calling the paginate function?

**This is the paginationClicked function. The culprit. It works fine to call the pagination function inside of that since the $(this) keyword refers to the anchor element. However, it does not when I call the pagination function within the buttonClicked function.**

```
function paginationClicked() {
    // Removes all the sibling anchor elements classes.
    $(this).parent().parent().children().children().removeClass("active");
    // Adds the class active to the selected anchor.
    currentPagPage = $(this).text();
    console.log(currentPagPage);
    paginate(allStudentsArr, $(this).text());

}
```

**This is the event handlers:**

```
// Event click handler that targets the pagination buttons.
$(".pagination a").click(paginationClicked);

$("button").click(buttonClicked);
```

Please feel free to ask if something seems unclear. I have been on this for hours and I can't seem to find a solution.

Some guidelines would be hugely appreciated. Cheers.

Here is my code:
https://github.com/SebastianPeterAndersson/Pagination-And-Content-Filter/blob/master/js/pagination-content-filter.js

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code directly in the question body.

Comment: `$(this) != this`. *this* is a keyword that references an object set by the call (or maybe undefined in strict mode), `$(this)` is a jQuery object.

Comment: So would the 'this' keyword work? Sorry I'm not that experienced hence the need for more specificity.

Comment: Within `buttonClicked()` can you just say `$("a.active").text()`? You're talking about the "active" anchor - is it the one with the "active" class? (There's a comment in `paginationClicked()` that says "// Adds the class active" but the function doesn't actually do that.) Or does each button have its own related anchor?

Comment: Maybe I should have posted it on codepen right away. http://codepen.io/SebastianSapien/pen/jAjwQz

Comment: I have no idea how that disappeared. I updated it on codepen and github. The function refers to a click handler down below. Sorry for the inconvenience I didn't think it through. I will add it to the stackoverflow question.

Comment: OK, so as per my previous comment, within `buttonClicked()` can't you say `paginate(userSearchArr, $("a.active").text());`? (Assuming there will always be exactly one active anchor...)

Comment: No that does not seem to work. The anchor elements does not respond at all when the search array is in use. Yes there will always be one.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "does not respond". If the anchor exists on the page and has the "active" class then `$("a.active").text()` should get its text.

Comment: The anchor responds when I initially load the page. But when I search for an object in the list with the search function the buttons seem to be disabled. I don't really know why but I am looking intensively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you construct totally new list of `anchor` when someone searches for something.

When you remove the old pagination, all `anchor` would be gone, along with their event handlers. You need to move the event registration into your `constructPagPages` function

move this:

```js
// Event click handler that targets the pagination buttons.
$(".pagination a").click(paginationClicked);
```

into your `constructPagPages` function, after you construct the pagination.

Have a look here: http://codepen.io/mrducnguyen/pen/xOoLPV